# Further simplify this: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\cdot a^k\cdot b^{n-k}\cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

<del>I know the simplified form of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\cdot a^k\cdot b^k\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}$, which is $\frac{(a+b)^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a\cdot (n+1)}$, I am wandering if there exists the simplified form of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\cdot a^k\cdot b^k\cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$?</del>

EDIT：

Sorry that it should be $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\cdot a^k\cdot b^{n-k}\cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$, my mistake.

Comment: The formulas as written depend only on $ab$.
Do you mean for one of the exponents to be $n-k$ instead of $k$?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes! Thanks! It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No simple form, this summation tends to be a generalized hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 2):

$$
{\rm f}\left(\mu\right)
\equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{\mu^{k + 1} \over \left(k + 1\right)^{2}}\,,
\quad
{\rm f}'\left(\mu\right)
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{\mu^{k} \over k + 1}\,,
\quad
\left[\mu{\rm f}\left(\mu\right)\right]'
=
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\mu^{k}
=
\left(1 + \mu\right)^{n}
$$

$$
\mu{\rm f}'\left(\mu\right)
=
{\left(1 + \mu\right)^{n + 1} - 1 \over n + 1}\,,
\qquad
{\rm f}\left(\mu\right)
=
{1 \over n + 1}
\int_{0}^{\mu}{\left(1 + \mu'\right)^{n + 1} - 1 \over \mu'}\,{\rm d}\mu'
$$

$$
\color{#ff0000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{a^{k}b^{k} \over \left(k + 1\right)^{2}}}
=
{1 \over ab}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
{\left(ab\right)^{k + 1} \over \left(k + 1\right)^{2}}
=
\color{#ff0000}{{1 \over \left(n + 1\right)ab}
\int_{0}^{ab}{\left(1 + \mu\right)^{n + 1} - 1 \over \mu}\,{\rm d}\mu}
$$
After integration by parts the integration is reduced to a limit of a Incomplete Beta function derivative. This is related to a hypergeometric one.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. There was a mistake in my formula (see the EDIT), and could you please tell me if it affects your answer? (Or maybe you could help edit your answer, thanks!)

Comment: I guess so. I will recheck tomorrow since it's too late.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait for your update.

Comment: Hi, I am wandering if you get any progress on this?

Comment: @peter I didn't work out anything besides the above result.